# Spring boot 2x + Kafka API produce JSON object instead of String/Generic

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

How code looks at the moment: (template)

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaConfiguration {

    @Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapServers;

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> producerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, Object> producerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfigs());
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, Object> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }

    public void send(String topicName, Object body) {
        kafkaTemplate.send(topic, body);
    }
    //In send method i am sending simple json in string format: {"name":"Leo", "age": "51"}
    //Would be better if i change object to JSON type and which type should   
    // i provide?
}
```

In which type should i send this string in best way?
Should i use something like JSONObject? Or should i use ObjectMapper to get json from this string?

Comment: it is always a better approach to use JSON payload for producing messages.

Comment: @vaibhavsahu in this case, with which type could i replace String than?

Comment: @vai Not necessarily. Structured binary formats are "better" than JSON in terms of performance and network/disk resource saving

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is always a better approach to use JSON payload for producing messages.

you can write a custom method to serialize String to JSON

```
private final static ObjectWriter writer = new ObjectMapper().writerFor(TopicRecord.class);
private String serialize(TopicRecord topicRecord) {
    try {
      return writer.writeValueAsString(topicRecord);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Unable to serialize topic record to json", e);
    }
  }
```

Comment: One question, woudn't it be better to send JSONObject instead of String which contains json?

Comment: @smith If you don't have a POJO class, you can send JSONObject, yes

Comment: This block of code is what JsonSerializer basically already does. Why rewrite?

Comment: @OneCricketeer thanks man, good luck in life bro